# BackgroundTask every minute Windows Store App (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, intervals

So after much searching through the internet and trial and errors I've constructed a backgroundTask in a W8 App. But apperently the windows BackgroundTask class does only allow you to have a interval of 15 minutes.

Though for the application I'm developing is this useless. I need a interval of max 1 minute. Does anyone know a working workaround for a background task to run with the app suspended in a max interval of 1 minute?

Comment: Can you explain what your application does and why you need such a high refresh rate? Perhaps there is another way to solve the problem that does not involve a timer trigger.

Comment: The app reads a Json API from a service

Comment: That's a bit like saying, "So why are you in jail?", "For breaking prole". What kind of service are you using that taking 14 more minutes makes it "worthless". I could see a app that tracks stock prices fall in to that category, but why make us guess?

Comment: Because it is inrelevant information, The service nor the API are the problem. The problem is how windows handles the backgroundtasks. I'm trying to read downloads from SabNBZd.

Comment: @s.lenders - Why do you need to read that every minute?  And have you considered [push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx) instead of a background task?

Comment: To send notifications when the status of a download changes. 15 minutes are to much, if it was 5 or so I won't mind but 15 minutes is a age. Push Notifications are nice but not for this purpose. You see i don't have a cloud service that can send a push notification.

Comment: Ugh.  I'd hate an app which notified me every minute of the status of my downloads.  One notification when it's done is sufficient.  You can look at the [background transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452979.aspx) API to see if it has a "done notification".  And if that doesn't do it for you, the answer is "No, there is no way."  Just like there's no way to run iOS on a Windows phone, you're limited by what the software allows.  And it doesn't allow what you want.

Comment: 1 if its done is the goal, but if you recieve that 15 minutes after you already opened it then it has no use.

Comment: @s.lenders - How would you receive it 15 minutes after you open it?  If the app is open, you don't need a background task.  If the app is not open, then you aren't looking at the transfer.  If the background task is running and the user opens your app, you should kill it if the transfer is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977046.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj160504.aspx)), there's no way to schedule it more frequently than every 15 minutes.  Your question implies you already knew this, however.

I don't think there is going to be a workaround available, and even if you found one, I'm pretty sure that would be grounds for having your app rejected from the store.

Comment: I know it is not possible by now and i'm searching for a workaround. I understand why microsoft doesn't like a lower interval, due to alot of the devices running on battery power. But that is something i have to try. The purpose of the app is totally worthless if i can only have a task interval of 15 minutes

Comment: @s.lenders - The app is also worthless if it's rejected from the app store for violating their rules.

Comment: Not for personal use, though there might be plans to publish it on later date

Comment: @s.lenders - True enough, although then it's not a "Windows Store App" question any more.  I'll add another answer with a theoretical workaround, but I have no idea whether or not it would actually work.

Answer (score 0):

One theoretical approach you can take (I haven't tried this, and I haven't tried to research if it would work) is to have 15 separate background tasks, one for each minute.

Depending on how Windows handles launching background tasks, you can either try to schedule 15 separate tasks with 15 separate delays until they start, or 15 tasks that all run at once with differing `Thread.Sleep()` delays in them.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but not possible. Windows 8 has a built-in timer that runs background tasks in 15-minute intervals. Windows it self runs the tasks that have been overdue. So if i set the interval to 15 it could be it takes 29 minutes to actually happen, if the task registers just on the call of the backgroundtask interval. So its not the program that calls the background task, it is the windows backgroundtask service

Comment: @s.lenders - Can you register more than one task?  And can those tasks sleep for up to 14 minutes in the middle of executing?  You may have to wait for up to 14 minutes for the first task to kick off, but once it does, one task would wake up each minute.  I strongly suspect you can't use `Sleep` for that duration, though.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for personal use as your comments suggests, the app sound more like a desktop app.

But alternative you could do the app backend as a windows service or normal win32 app and then create a windows store app for nice frontend that gets its information over localhost http.