# Windows Store App background task to be run every minute?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, task, backgroundworker

Im writing windows store application which require to sync the data every one minute, 2 minute or 5 minute as per user's selection (it is a must requirement from the client). As I learn, it is not possible to run the background task less than 15 minutes. Is there a way to implement? This is for a tab based applications targeting Windows 8.1

If I manually write a thread to run the sync every minute, where should the thread class and functionality be placed so that it wont be stopped when user switch pages?

I know this question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916376/backgroundtask-every-minute-windows-store-app-c). But asking again in case if anyone has found a way or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

No. In Windows Phone, you do not have much control to run Background Task. Background task may even closed by operating system, if user is not actually interacting with system time.

One way around is to send push notification, but that is not feasible in all the cases.

Comment: Thanks. This is for a tab based applications targeting Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this class in Windows Phone to refresh a list of Items every minute from the server using AsyncSockets, maybe you can modify this class for your needs (maybe you want to store some data aswell)

```
public class BackgroundWorker : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly BackgroundWorker SingleWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public static BackgroundWorker GetInstance()
    {
        return SingleWorker;
    }

    private readonly Thread _worker;
    private bool _disposed = false;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _are = new AutoResetEvent(false); //can't remeber if it is true or false

    private BackgroundWorker()
    {
        _worker = new Thread(HandleWorker);
        _worker.Start();
    }

    private void HandleWorker()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _are.Reset();

            //Check if there is work to be done
            //Do Work


            _are.Set();

            //Add a wait here Like wait for 2 minutes before you continue
        }
    }

    public void WaitForCompletion()
    {
        if (_disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name,"Object cannot be accessed when disposed");
        _are.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposed = true;
        _worker.Abort(0x0);
        _are.Set();
    }
}
```